# How do you disable vertical scroll and render a modal at the current position of the page rather than at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css, sass, vuejs2, vue-component

This is my single file Vue component which has a modal.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">      
      <div class="sidebar">
        <button class="sidebar__gradient-button" @click="setModalVisible(true)" >Open Modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div v-if="modalVisible" class="modal">
      <div class="modal__card">
        <div class="modal__card__container">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal__close-button" @click="setModalVisible(false)">×</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->

    <!-- Modal Overlay -->
    <div v-if="modalVisible" class="overlay" />
    <!-- Modal Overlay -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      modalVisible: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setModalVisible: function(val) {
      console.log(val);
      return (this.modalVisible = val);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "../../sass/app.scss";
</style>
```

On smaller screens, the modal open button is not at the top of the page however, the modal and the overlay render at the top of the page.

There are two things I would like to do:

1. Disable vertical scroll
2. Render the modal and overlay at the current position on the page (I do not want to snap scroll to top and I am anti-jQuery :D)

Here is the styling for the modal in Sass:

```
.modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 130px;
    @media #{$breakpoint-sm} {
        margin-top: 0;
        align-items: center;
        @media #{$breakpoint-md} {
        }
    }
}

.modal__card {
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 272px;
    width: 355px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    @media #{$breakpoint-sm} {
        height: 310px;
        width: 570px;
        @media #{$breakpoint-md} {
        }
    }
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #262626;
    opacity: 0.8;
    mix-blend-mode: normal;
}
```

Please assist. I imagine that the "top" property needs to be dynamically set, somehow. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add overflow: hidden and padding-right on your body when the modal is open to replace scrollbar width with this function

```
function getScrollbarWidth() {
  return window.innerWidth - document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}
```

Comment: Replace position: absolute to position: fixed